# Metodos inaccesibles desde application class (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Pues resulta que desde la clase que extiende de Application() accedo a las otras clases del proyecto pero no veo sus metodos (unresolved reference).

Esta es la clase application:

```
package com.fernando.lanatelar
import android.app.Application

class LanaTelarApp : Application() {

    companion object Constants {
        const val TAG = "ObjectBoxExample"
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ObjectBox.construye(this)
    }
}
```

Y esta es la clase ObjectBox:

```
package com.fernando.lanatelar

import android.content.Context
import com.fernando.lanatelar.modelo.MyObjectBox
import io.objectbox.BoxStore

class ObjectBox {
    lateinit var boxStore: BoxStore
        private set

    fun construye(context: Context) {
        boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(context.applicationContext).build()
    }
}
```

Desde LanaTelarApp accedo a ObjectBox sin problemas, pero no me aparecen sus metodos y al poner ObjectBox.construye() me da error de : Unresolved 
reference.

El manifest está asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fernando.lanatelar">
    <application
        android:name=".LanaTelarApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te han indicado, si no instancias la clase, la única forma es acceder a un método estático, que debe estar dentro de companion object.  Si no quieres crear un método estático, es necesario instanciar la clase:

```
val objectBox = ObjectBox()
```

y ahora sí puedes llamar al método:

```
 objectBox.construye()
```

De todas formas, en tu caso en particular, te vendría bien que la clase ObjectBox no sea una **class**, sino un **object**.  Con esto ya puedes llamar directamente al método **construye** y además consigues una única instancia de este objeto.

Answer (score -1):

¿Te refieres a metodos estaticos? Eso se declara declarando el metodo dentro de un bloque [`companion object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects). Esto es lo equivalente a `static` en Java:

```
class ObjectBox {
    lateinit var boxStore: BoxStore
    private set

    companion object  {

        fun construye(context: Context) {
            boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(context.applicationContext).build()
        }
    } 
}
```

Entonces podras acceder al metodo construye utilizando la clase como identificador:

```
  // ...
    ObjectBox.construye(this);
  //...
```

Comment: Ok. Gracias. Lo pruebo.